# I can't work like this!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

Soon after arriving to work this morning, I sent an email off to my pal over in IT upon realizing that my workstation wasn't fully functional. We both like to solve puzzles in our spare time, so rather than reveal precisely what I was expecting from him, I let him work it out for himself.

> Hey, Mike!
>
> Quick question -- is there any chance you've got a certain piece of equipment sitting on a shelf somewhere? Mine is no longer working correctly, even after a thorough cleaning of the components. If you can't locate one, I guess you'll just have to requisition a new one. You can ask my manager to sign off. Shoot me an email to let me know what to expect.
>
> Thanks!
>   - C
>
> P.S. I know my request is puzzling to say the least, but that's the point! I guarantee that this email contains all the information necessary for you to figure it out. Have fun!

**What am I expecting Mike to get for me & why?**

---

<sub>*Folks who were there for the original version of this (you know who you are)... shhhh!*</sub>

Comment: Should we assume the email came from your workstation, and not a secondary device (phone, someone else's computer, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, it came from my personal (semi-functional) workstation.

Comment: Please tell me you didn't really do this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Could you be asking for a

> new keyboard ?

Because

> the letter 'd' no longer works

Which explains why

> you had to make a puzzle of it, not being able to ask for a keyboar(**d**)

Also

> keyboard is really the most dust/dirt prone piece of equipment in a workstation, and the one that needs to be cleaned regularly

Comment: Good analysis! Though before the advent of optical mice, I found myself constantly scraping the gunk off of mouse balls from common use computers.

Comment: you mean... with a Q tip? :)

Comment: No, by popping them out and using my fingernails. :)

Comment: I used to do it with a Q tip or a toothpick

Comment: @feelinferrety: ["Relevant"](https://www.snopes.com/humor/business/mouse.asp) (not relevant).

Comment: I’m not volunteering for a ball twistoff

Comment: @feelinferrety: I use a trackball at work, I'm still cleaning gunk (off the rollers, not the ball).

Comment: @flater D'oh! Shows how long it's been since I had to do it. You're totally right. The rollers, not the ball. >_<

Comment: @feelinferrety ...I didn't even mean to correct you. But you're welcome ;)

Comment: You can still ask for a "keyboard" using a variety of different methods even if your 'd' key doesn't work. Copy/Paste from other text, on-screen keyboard, [Alt] + 100, etc...

Answer (score 3):

This is based on the assumption that the email was sent from your workstation, in which case, you are looking for

> a mouse/trackball

Because...

> The computer has to be turned on and functional to send the email.  You also need a keyboard to input the email, as well as select the email application, generate the new email, and choose the recipients, all of which can be done from a keyboard.  You also need a functioning monitor to make sure that you are making the correct choices.  A mouse, however, is an input that some people can do without, but is nice to have.

Why do I think this?

> I work in IT and have seen requests like this before.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct!

Answer (score 1):

> A camera, because unlike a keyboard and mouse you don't need it on your desk, which explains it being on a shelf, and you could have tried cleaning the lens because you thought that it was dirty but after that it still didn't work

Comment: C asks whether Mike, the IT guy, has the item in question stinning somewhere on a storage shelf. This doesn't tell you anything how or where the item is supposed to be used.